# Evenly distribute a number of columns in x by a max amount per set

Tags: javascript

Is there an algorithm in javascript to evenly distribute a number of columns in X by a max amount of per set?

For example, in the following scenarios:

---

- Number of columns is 11.
- Max number per set 5.
- Answer would be 4,4,3

---

- Number of columns is 12
- Max number per set is 5
- Answer would be 4, 4, 4

---

- Number of Columns is 15
- Max number per set is 5
- Answer would be 5, 5, 5

---

- Number of Columns is 13
- Max number per set is 5
- Answer would be 5,4,4

Comment: No, there is not. You'll have to create this yourself. You can look into `.reduce` and `.splice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with these steps:

- Calculate how many items the final array will have.
- Create an array of that length, with every entry as the max number. This probably overflows the number of columns, but:
- Iterate through that array, subtracting 1 from each value until we are at the desired number of columns.

Which should result in your desired, mostly evenly-split array. Example:

```js
function makeEvenSpread(numCol, maxNum) {
    // Length of final array. This is fixed so we can calculate it up front.
    const len = Math.ceil(numCol/maxNum);
    
    // An array of that length, filled with the maxNum. Probably this overflows
    // the numColumns constraint, which we fix in the next step.
    const overflowed = new Array(len).fill(maxNum);
    
    // This is how much the overflowed array's sum exceeds numCol.
    let over = len*maxNum - numCol;
    
    // Now you need to go through the array and subtract one from each element
    // in turn, until we hit the desired sum. If we get to the end of the array,
    // start again from the beginning.
    let ind = 0;
    while (over--) {
        overflowed[ind++%len]--;
    }
    
    // You want the smaller numbers at the end, so reverse the result.
    return overflowed.reverse();
}

console.log(makeEvenSpread(11, 5)) // [4, 4, 3]
console.log(makeEvenSpread(12, 5)) // [4, 4, 4]
console.log(makeEvenSpread(15, 5)) // [5, 5, 5]
console.log(makeEvenSpread(13, 5)) // [5, 4, 4]
```